# Update taxonomy field from ACF field when saving post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code where I am updating the car_year taxonomy field from acf field field_611eb3690a472 when saving post and in the second function I am trying to update the car_fuel_type from the acf field field_612cfc339a8ba but at the same time change the value depending on the acf field value.
The first car_year field update works just fine but the car_fuel_type field doesn't get any value.

**Why is that ? Could you post a similar example so I can see what the problem is?**

Here is my code into the functions.php file:

```
add_action('save_post', '__hp_frd_year');
function __hp_frd_year($post_id) {
    $release_date = !empty($_POST['acf']['field_611eb3690a472']) ? $_POST['acf']['field_611eb3690a472'] : '';
    $year = !empty($_POST['acf']['field_588f336aabaa6']) ? $_POST['acf']['field_588f336aabaa6'] : '';
    $release_date_year = date("Y", strtotime($release_date) );
    $new_term = wp_insert_term(
        $release_date_year,   // the term 
        'car_year', // the taxonomy
        array(
            'description' => '',
            'slug'        => strtolower($release_date_year),
        )
    );
    if(!is_wp_error($new_term)) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_term['term_id'], 'car_year' );
    } else {
        $term_added = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_term->error_data['term_exists'], 'car_year' );
    }
}

/**
 * Fuel type data and fuel_type acf fields
 */
add_action('save_post', '__hp_fuel_type');
function __hp_fuel_type($post_id) {
    $fuel_type_acf = !empty($_POST['acf']['field_612cfc339a8ba']) ? $_POST['acf']['field_612cfc339a8ba'] : '';
    $fuel_type_acf_lang ==  '';
    
    if ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ') {
//  if ($fuel_type_acf  == "ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ"){
        $fuel_type_acf_lang = '[:el]ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ[:en]UNLEADED[:]';
    }else{if ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ') {
//      if ($fuel_type_acf  == "ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ"){
        $fuel_type_acf_lang = '[:el]ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ[:en]DIESEL[:]';
    }else{if ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΑΕΡΙΟ') {
//      if ($fuel_type_acf  == "ΑΕΡΙΟ"){
        $fuel_type_acf_lang = '[:el]ΑΕΡΙΟ[:en]GAS[:]';
    }else{if ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ') {
//      if ($fuel_type_acf  == "ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ"){
        $fuel_type_acf_lang = '[:el]ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ[:en]HYBRID / UNLEADED[:]';
    }else{if ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ') {
//      if ($fuel_type_acf  == "ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ"){
        $fuel_type_acf_lang = '[:el]ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ[:en]HYBRID / DIESEL[:]';
    }else{if ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΟ') {
//      if ($fuel_type_acf  == "ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΟ"){
        $fuel_type_acf_lang = '[:el]ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΟ[:en]ELECTRIC[:]';
}}}}}}

    $new_term = wp_insert_term(
        $fuel_type_acf_lang,   // the term 
        'car_fuel_type', // the taxonomy
        array(
            'description' => '',
            'slug'        => strtolower($fuel_type_acf_lang),
        )
    );
    if(!is_wp_error($new_term)) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_term['term_id'], 'car_fuel_type' );
    } else {
        $term_added = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_term->error_data['term_exists'], 'car_fuel_type' );
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: insted of else else else else, you should use a switch case, or `elseif{}`

Comment: I changed all the }else{if (...) to }elseif (...) statements but that didn't solve the problem I am describing... The car_fuel_type field still doesn't get any value..... Thanks

Comment: Anyone has an idea on how to do this??? No One ! ! 1

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out :

```
add_action('save_post', '__hp_fuel_type');
function __hp_fuel_type($post_id) {
$fuel_type_acf = !empty($_POST['acf']['field_612cfc339a8ba']) ? $_POST['acf']['field_612cfc339a8ba'] : '';    
if (((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ') || ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'UNLEADED')) {
    $fuel_type_acf = '[:el]ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ[:en]UNLEADED[:]';
}else{if (((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ') ||  ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'DIESEL')) {
    $fuel_type_acf = '[:el]ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ[:en]DIESEL[:]';
}else{if (((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΑΕΡΙΟ') || ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'GAS')) {
    $fuel_type_ac = '[:el]ΑΕΡΙΟ[:en]GAS[:]';
}else{if (((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ') || ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'HYBRID / UNLEADED')) {
    $fuel_type_acf = '[:el]ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ[:en]HYBRID / UNLEADED[:]';
}else{if (((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ') || ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'HYBRID / DIESEL')) {
    $fuel_type_acf = '[:el]ΥΒΡΙΔΙΚΟ / ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ[:en]HYBRID / DIESEL[:]';
}else{if (((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΟ') ||  ((isset($fuel_type_acf) ? $fuel_type_acf : null) == 'ELECTRIC')) {
    $fuel_type_acf = '[:el]ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΟ[:en]ELECTRIC[:]';}}}}}}
$new_term = wp_insert_term(
    $fuel_type_acf,   // the term 
    'car_fuel_type', // the taxonomy
    array(
        'description' => '',
        'slug'        => strtolower($fuel_type_acf),
    )
);
if(!is_wp_error($new_term)) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_term['term_id'], 'car_fuel_type' );
} else {
    $term_added = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_term->error_data['term_exists'], 'car_fuel_type' );
}}
```